# Knowing that $G(s)$ is a PRG, is the following construction $G'(s) = G(s||0)$ a PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I know there already is a very similar question. However, I can't understand why $G'(s)$ is not a PRG. If $G(s)$ is a PRG, then why $G(s||0)$ can't also be a PRG? How can the distribution over $G(s||0)$ be distinguished from a truly uniform distribution of the same output range?

Comment: Please note that the input $s$ must be defined as: $s\leftarrow \{0,1\}^n$. In other words, $s$ must be chosen uniformly at random, whereas in your case $s||0$ is not a uniformly random value.

Comment: Oh, so based on the non-true randomness of the seed, is legitimate to conclude that the corresponding construction can't possibly be pseudorandom?

Comment: Yes, I refer you to "introduction to modern cryptography" , 1st edition, page 213-214.

Comment: Ok. Could you please add an answer as your first comment above, so that the question can be completed? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user13676 The seed is $s$, and it is uniformly chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Knowing that $G(s)$ is a PRG, is the following construction $G'(s) = G(s||0)$ a PRG?

Maybe.

> If $G(s)$ is a PRG, then why $G(s||0)$ can't also be a PRG?

$G'$ *can* "also be a PRG". (It's just *not necessarily* also a PRG.)

> How can the distribution over $G(s||0)$ be distinguished from a truly uniform distribution of the same output range?"

$G$ can be such that the last bit of its output is always equal to the last bit of its input.

Comment: "The last bit of $G$'s output can always equal the last bit of $G$'s input" - now this is what I don't understand, because you're assuming to know that in advance (how? why?). The only thing I see here is that the input to $G$ has an extra bit at index '0' fixed to $0$, but this doesn't say you nothing about the possible output, this doesn't mean that the output's bit at index '0' will also be 0 (it can also be 1, as $G$ is pseudorandom).

Comment: It is possible that the last bit of $G$'s output equals the last bit of the seed, in this case $G'$ is not a pseudorandom generator.

Comment: One can "know that in advance" by choosing $G$. $\:$ "this doesn't say you nothing about the possible output," which is why the answer to your title is "Maybe". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: As a simulated example: say the seed is uniformly chosen from $\{{0,1}\}^4$, for example $[0100]$, and the expansion factor is twice the input length. Suppose $G(0100) = 11101010$, so in this case "the last bit of $G$'s output equals the last bit of the seed", which is $0$. Then what can be said about $G'(0100) = G(01000)$ in order to conclude what you're stating?

Comment: That depends entirely on the rest of $G$'s description. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer - I totally accept your answer and I'm thankful for that, but you're not giving me any proof of why and how. I'm trying to simulate every possible scenario including yours, in order to find an explanation, but without success. This way your answer doesn't really give me any extra help, I'm seeing it as futile (notice I'm not saying it's not correct, it can be 100% correct, but it doesn't help me at all if you don't argue your answer).

Comment: @pa5h1nh0 What exactly do you want a proof of? It is impossible to prove that $G'$ is or is not a pseudorandom generator, because both cases are possible. Your "example" is not an example at all: a pseudorandom generator is an algorithm and it is in general impossible to analyse it without its complete description.

Comment: @pa5h1nh0 Also, I notice that answers to your questions tend to have a comment thread which degenerates into a discussion, which is not allowed here. You must ask precise questions so that it is possible to know what you are asking without a discussion.

Comment: @fkraiem I understand that, and you're right about the comment thread, but my question is pretty precise and simple: you take a $G(s)$ which is believed to be a 99% PRG, is $G(s||0)$ a PRG? [Yes | No | impossible to prove] ... from your comment I understand there doesn't exist an answer to this question, right? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, what's a "99% PRG"? Either $G$ is a PRG or it is not. Second, that's not how your original question is worded: your question was "why $G'$ can't be a PRG?" There is no general answer as to whether or not $G'$ is a PRG, as both cases are possible. It is possible that $G$ is a PRG and that $G'$ is, and it is also possible that $G$ is a PRG and $G'$ is not.

Comment: "99%" because in the real world there's no actual proof of having a true PRG... and one last thing, after this one I'll conclude the comment thread: you both (with @RickyDemer) stated that "the distribution over $G(s||0)$ can be distinguished from a truly uniform distribution of the same output range". Doesn't this imply, therefore, that it can't be pseudorandom? Doesn't the pseudorandomness require indistinguishability from a truly uniform distribution over the same range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26436/discussion-between-pa5h1nh0-and-fkraiem).

Comment: I don't do chat (I have too many discussion channels to monitor as it is...). Feel free to send me an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

no , assuming the existence of a PRG G , then you can construct another PRG H , H defined as follow : $H(s_1,,,,s_n)=G(s_1||s_2||...||s_{n-1})||s_n$ , you can prove that H is indeed a PRG , so if you use H instead of G in your construction above , you will get that the last bit is always 0 which is obviously not a PRG.